# How to pass jQuery result to number field max attribute in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am working with a form that populates by an autocomplete jQuery script. It populate the product code, product name, quantity and Id. the form and the scripts are working very well. My problem is I realize I need to set the jquery quantity result to be the value of MAX attribute in my number field (quantity field) unfortunately I am just started learning to code in jQuery.

Here's the row from my form:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt product_code" type='text' data-type="product_code" id='product_code_1' name='' for="1" required/></td>
    <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt product_name" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='' for="1" required/></td>
    <td><input class="form-control qty_in" type='number' data-type="qty_in" id='qty_in_1' name='qty_in[]' min='' max=''for="1" required/></td>
    <input class="form-control product_id" type='hidden' data-type="product_id" id='product_id_1' name='product_id[]'/>
    <input class="form-control" type='hidden' id='user_id' name='user_id' value='{{ auth()->user()->id }}' /> 
    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Here's what it look like
[image]

Here's the autocomplete jquery script

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 
  // if(type =='qty_in' )autoType='qty_in'; 
  // if(type =='product_id' )autoType='id'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchStock') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item[autoType],
                           value: item[autoType],
                           data : item
                       }
                   });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
       },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
           var data = ui.item.data;           
           id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
           id = id_arr.split("_");
           elementId = id[id.length-1];
           $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
           $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
           $('#qty_in_'+elementId).val(data.qty_in);
           $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
       }
   });
});
```

My problem is how can I set the data.qty_in as a MAX value of my quantity number field attribute? So that it prevent the user from entering an amount greater than the data.qty_in into the quantity input. thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to prevent the user from entering an amount greater than the `data.qty_in` into the quantity input?

Comment: Yes @Adam exactly. how will it be possible?

Comment: Yo can prevent it with setting input field as number:
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
and: $('#qty_in_'+elementId).attr("max",data.qty_in);
But, this can not prevent someone to force update of that input to be larger than MAX, so you will still need some backend validation...

Comment: How about this code,                             <script type="text/javascript">
                                var $orderItem_id = {{$order_item_id}};
                                $('#stock_in_qty_'+$orderItem_id).on('mouseup keyup', function () {
                                    $(this).val(Math.min({{$remainingDeliveries}}, Math.max(0, $(this).val())));
                                });
                            </script> can we rewrite this?